# How to start phoenix.server as daemon

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

The below command run the phoenix.server in production mode and is given as the command for deploying phoenix.

```
MIX_ENV=prod PORT=4001 iex -S mix phoenix.server
```

However, the above command run the server interactively and closing the terminal, stops the phoenix.server from running. How to have phoenix.server run in the background?

Comment: Great question @shankardevy! It is asked from time to time and we plan to make it clearer.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
MIX_ENV=prod PORT=4001 elixir --erl "-detached" -S mix phx.server
```

Check `elixir --help` for more information.

Comment: can this information be added to http://www.phoenixframework.org/v0.12.0/docs/deployment ? It would help others find the right information at the right place.

Comment: Please do send a pull request to the guides repo: github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix-guides

Comment: What if the host was rebooted?

Comment: I mean, how to start phoenix automatically once the host it self get rebooted?

Comment: Hi jose what if i am using exrm?

Comment: @simo You can start using `@reboot` in `cron`, and run it in `screen` as well so you can attach to it.

Comment: Or user rc.local to execute this command, maybe with custom user, etc..

Comment: I have created the PR here: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/pull/3508